# Spark SQL: Why this unsupported language feature error for simple query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Query = select F1,SM3 from B1 where SM4 > 10

The parse tree is created.

14/10/13 14:48:32 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select F1,SM3 from B1 where SM4 > 10

14/10/13 14:48:32 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed

But in node to plan translation, it simply fails! The work around is to remove where clause..

```
TOK_QUERY
 TOK_FROM
  TOK_TABREF
   TOK_TABNAME
    B1
TOK_INSERT
  TOK_DESTINATION
   TOK_DIR
    TOK_TMP_FILE
TOK_SELECT
  TOK_SELEXPR
    TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
      F1
  TOK_SELEXPR
    TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
      SM3
TOK_WHERE
  >
    TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
      SM4
    10
```

Comment: I think that at the current stage of Spark SQL the best is to ask the mailing list: user@spark.apache.org

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and ended up having to use two queries. First I did SELECT * WHERE stuff and registered a new temp table, then I did my real query. That worked, but it's cumbersome.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Can you provide a [short example that reproduces the issue](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error was probably because I was using Spark (SQL) 1.1.0 with Hive 0.13 binaries.

I found that the parser was unable to recognize '10' as a valid numerical value inspite of it being tokenized correctly (It had token type as 290 as seen in the code). On removing the Hive 0.13 references it seems to work!